# Cleaning staging area Error:Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a map reduce code on hadoop and getting the following error:

> INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/dataflair/hdata/mapred/staging/intern124288574/.staging/job_local124288574_0001
>   Exception in thread "main" ExitCodeException exitCode=1: chmod: cannot access '/home/dataflair/hdata/mapred/staging/intern124288574/.staging/job_local124288574_0001': No such file or directory

```
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:998)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:884)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1310)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1292)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:767)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:506)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:487)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:503)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:720)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.mkdirs(JobResourceUploader.java:648)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadResourcesInternal(JobResourceUploader.java:167)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadResources(JobResourceUploader.java:128)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1588)
at wordCount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Comment: The file you're trying to access is not allowing you the permission. To solve this, you have to explicitly change the file permissions on your own.

Comment: But its trying to access a file which is directly under home directory which should be a user directory i guess. And also no such directory already exists Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is the case, then what happens is that your application is finding the dir which is not presently there. Try to create a dir by yourself and provide appropriate permission to that dir. Sometimes, this is the work around

Comment: Yeah but directory its searching is directly under home. Can i even make a directory there i mean there should be my username in between noe.  Like home/{usename}/dataflair/...

Comment: For me adding this property to yarn-site.xml worked.. <property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
 <value>/home/{username}/</value>
 </property>

Comment: Okay. Thanks for sharing